# Error while accessing dynamically allocated array between classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, 2d

UPDATE: Most of my relevant source code is in this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/nhAx1jfG

Can anyone make sense of this error?  I'm trying to access a 2d "Tile" array I declare in a different class in the same namespace, it's public, and I do declare an object in the main "rouge.cpp" class.

```
g++ -Wall -Werror -lncurses -c rouge.cpp -o rouge.o
rouge.cpp: In function ‘void update_game(Player, Map, World, bool)’:
rouge.cpp:497: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(world.World::tiles + ((((unsigned int)player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::x) + 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffu) * 16u))[player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::y]’
rouge.cpp:506: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(world.World::tiles + ((((unsigned int)player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::x) + 1u) * 16u))[player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::y]’
rouge.cpp:515: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(world.World::tiles + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::x) * 16u)))[(player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::y + -0x00000000000000001)]’
rouge.cpp:524: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(world.World::tiles + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::x) * 16u)))[(player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::y + 1)]’
rouge.cpp:540: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘*(world.World::tiles + ((unsigned int)(((unsigned int)player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::x) * 16u)))[player.Player::<anonymous>.GameObject::y]’
make: *** [rouge.o] Error 1
```

world.h:

```
// The "world" class, generates a world.
class World
{
    // Public classes and variables
    public:
        // Tile array
        Tile* tiles;
        int plates[WORLDSIZEX][WORLDSIZEY];
        //Tile tiles[WORLDSIZEX][WORLDSIZEY];
        //Tile (*tiles)[WORLDSIZEX] = new Tile[WORLDSIZEX][WORLDSIZEY];
        // For plates
        //int plates[WORLDSIZEX][WORLDSIZEY];
        //plates = new int[WORLDSIZEX][WORLDSIZEY];
        //int (*plates)[WORLDSIZEX] = new int[WORLDSIZEX][WORLDSIZEY];
        // Small world
        Tile smalltiles[SMALLWORLDX][SMALLWORLDY];
        // For world temp
        int worldtemp;
        // Constructor
        World();
        void generate_plates();
        bool check_plates();
        int build_mountains(int,int);
        void add_mountains();
        void generate_world();
        void shrink_world();
        void save_world();
        void erupt();
        bool get_passable(int,int);
        char get_icon(int,int);
        char get_small_icon(int,int);
        int get_color(int,int);
        int get_small_color(int,int);
};
```

world.cpp where I allocate the array:

```
// Constructor
World::World()
{
    // Seed for random number
    srand( time(NULL) );
    tiles = new Tile[WORLDSIZEX][WORLDSIZEY];
    // Generate a world
    generate_world();
    // Shrink world
    shrink_world();
    // Then save it.
    //save_world();
}
```

in rouge.cpp, I access it just like:

```
world.tiles[i][j]; //i and j are ints in a nested for loop
```

after I declare it like:

```
World world;
```

and it's spitting out that error

Comment: The error doesn't mean much without the code that causes it.

Comment: Yes, you should edit your post, and see some code there

Comment: there is a lot of code... but okay.

Comment: `0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffu` : The compiler is clearly quite enraged about something.

Comment: @Evan: Start with the line 497 + 10 lines either side. And the class definitions of any objects on line 497

Comment: @Evan: your errors are in function update_game() and you didn't include that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a pointer to point to an array that was dynamically allocated as a multidimensional array. After the address of this multidimensional array is stored in `World::tiles`, the compiler "forgets" that the array was multidimensional. Thus, you can no longer use the double brackets notation (`tiles[x][y]`) to access an element.

To get around this, you have at least 4 options:

1. Provide a method in World that takes x,y coordinates and returns a reference to the desired cell (you might want to provide both const and non-const versions):

   `Tile& at(size_t x, size_t y) {return tiles[y*WORLDSIZEX + x];}`

   `const Tile& at(size_t x, size_t y) const {return tiles[y*WORLDSIZEX + x];}`
2. Roll-up your own 2D array class for `World::tiles`.
3. Use a [boost::multi_array](http://tp://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) for `World::tiles`.
4. Declare `World::tiles` as `vector< vector<Tile> >`. The initial sizing of all nested vectors is tricky, but after that you can use the `world.tiles[x][y]` notation.

Plus the option @fsmc gave you.

---

I took a quick look at your code in the pastebin. It would be much more efficient (and cleaner looking) if you initialized your `tiles` vectors like this instead:

```
tiles.resize(WORLDSIZEX);
for(int i = 0; i < WORLDSIZEX; i++)
{
    tiles[i].resize(WORLDSIZEY);
}
```

Comment: I tried #4 and still was getting bizarre errors while trying to reference.  I'll replicate the error messages.

Comment: Actually, #4 works, but I'm still not able to make an array bigger than 512x512.

Comment: @Evan: Try running a stripped-down `main` where all you do is allocate `World`. See if it still crashes. If so, strip down `World`'s constructor so that all you do is allocate your tiles. If it no longer crashes, then you might have a dangling pointer bug somewhere else that only manifests itself when `World::tiles` takes up a lot of memory.

Comment: @Evan: What's in a tile anyway? How much memory does each tile use up?

Comment: Tile is puny, so it's clearly not a lack-of-memory problem. If you ran your program in a debugger, it might show you the exact line causing the segfault.

Comment: It's as soon as I create the World in rouge.cpp, in init_game().

Comment: Small nitpick: Rogue is spelled like this: rogue. The way you spell it is for the make-up ladies put on their cheeks. :-P

Comment: I know this.. it was a typo initially, and I just stuck with it.  I actually do call it "rouge" lol.

Answer (score 2):

`world.tiles` is of type Tile*.  It is the wrong type to be a two dimensional array (you would need `Tile**`, and need to initialize it in two steps (one to create an array of `Tile*` pointers, and a loop to create an array that each of those `Tile *` pointers can point to.

e.g. in your class def:

```
Tile **tiles
```

e.g.: in your constructor:

```
tiles = new Tile*[SMALLWORLDX];
for (int i = 0; i < SMALLWORLDX; i++)
   tiles[i] = new Tile[SMALLWORLDY];
```

So getting back to what was causing your original error- when you were calling `world.tiles[x][y]`, the first [] operator was okay, because tiles could be pointing to an array of `Tiles`, but the second one is not okay.

Comment: This is now my error:
g++ -Wall -Werror -lncurses -c world.cpp -o world.o
world.cpp: In constructor ‘World::World()’:
world.cpp:42: error: array bound forbidden after parenthesized type-id
world.cpp:42: note: try removing the parentheses around the type-id
make: *** [world.o] Error 1

Comment: Sorry, there was a syntax error.  You don't need the parens around new Tile*.  I updated the answer.

Comment: It then gives me the same problem I had before, which is, my 2d array is too big for the compiler to handle, and it fills up the stack and segfaults immediately.

Comment: How big is WORLDSIZEX and WORLDSIZEY?  Can you make them smaller to test?

Comment: When they are smaller it works, when they are each smaller than 512 it works.  When they are larger, I get segfaults.

Comment: Ok, so I guess Tile must be pretty big or you are working with tight memory requirements.  If neither of those are true it's probably something else.  At least your array problems are solved.

Comment: this was the whole reason I didn't just declare a Tile tiles[WORLDSIZEX][WORLDSIZEY].  I'm allocating memory globally... so I don't get why this is still giving me errors.  it should be using the static space of VM.

Comment: How big is Tile memory wise?  Also note that the array is just leaking unless you have added the cleanup code to the debugger.  I assumed your World world; declaration was global, so  I don't expect it to crash your program, but if you are doing something like creating lots of Worlds within a loop, this will crash eventually due to massive leaks.

Comment: I only create world (not globally, but in rouge.cpp inside of an init_game() function I call from the main loop before entering the update() loop) 1 time, and Tile has 1 int, and it is a child class of a "GameObject" class, which has a few ints and a char.

Comment: Okay then your error may not have to do with running out of memory.  If you are creating World in a function the way you listed above (World world;) this will be deconstructed at the end of that function.  Are you doing something like taking a pointer to it and storing that globally from within init_game()?  This is a nono.  Instead you should use a pointer and new World.

Comment: Your problem is that you are not taking pointers when you use World as a parameter to your functions.  This causes the program to create a new copy of World every time a function like draw is called.  You want your functions to look like draw(World* world, etc) and when you call it, call it like draw(&myGlobalWorldObject, etc)

Comment: Why would I pass pointers of world around?  Isn't using the '&' pass by reference?  Why would you ever just use World world or int x or double y if the function that receives them will be duplicating them?

Comment: @Evan: You should pass World around by pointer or reference because it is very large. Passing World by value would be very inefficient. World also has pointer members, so unless you're overloading the copy constructor and assignments operators to perform a deep copy, you're going to have major dangling pointer issues. I'm going to try to find a link for you that better explains these issues.

Comment: So the function prototypes should look like this:  
func(World*);  

function calls should look like this:  
func(&world);  

and function definitions should look like this:  
func(World* world)
{

}

Comment: @Evan: If `world` is a global object, then yes, that should work. I prefer to pass by reference whenever possible: `void func(World& world) {...}` invoked with `func(world)`.

Comment: world isn't global, I create world in my init_game() function in my main() of rouge.cpp.  what should my function headers/definition/calls look like if it's not a global object?

Comment: I'll have to look closer at your code. Meanwhile, take a look at this: http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/

Comment: Okay, I see the problem. You're doing the "nono" that fsmc talked about above. There are two way to fix this. I'll update my answer. Perhaps we should move our discussion over to my answer. I feel like I hijacked fsmc's comment section.

Comment: Oops, I misspoke. You're not committing the nono. The `world` object only needs to exist while you're looping inside `update_game`, right? Just use the `void func(World& world)` signature, and the shallow-copy problem will hopefully go away. Check out this link that talks about shallow vs. deep copy (http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/).

Comment: This worked!  YES!  You're amazing, thank you a billion times.

Comment: Cool. Make sure you read up on shallow/deep copying so that you understand *why* it fixed the problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just based on the error message, whatever you are trying to index is not actually an array. The '*' (dereference) operator at the beginning of that statement looks suspicious to me, but without actually seeing your code I can't say much else.